# Is it natural to use the word "cheaper" as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

Is it natural and correct to use the word *cheaper* as an adverb. For example:

> You have to pay a lot of money to have your phone fixed at the repair shop. I will do it **cheaper**.

Answer (score 2):

It is natural, but not correct in formal writing.

The correct, formal, use is **more cheaply**.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cheap_2

https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/adverb_steig.htm

Comment: Does that sentence look like formal writing? Just an FYI: informal English is as "correct" (whatever the heck that means) as formal English. In informal English, *cheaper* is fine and there's nothing wrong with it, but the word is confined to informal English (as the dictionary label indicates). *More cheaply* is neutral (I don't find it formal at all), and would therefore also be appropriate in all registers. Formal English is in no way more grammatical or "correct" than informal English, just so it's clear. Those are different registers, styles we're talking about here.

Comment: Cheaper is an adjective, cheaply is an adverb. As an English tutor, I would mark use of an adj in place of an adv as incorrect in a piece of written work for assessment.